# Switch raring to systemd

Tags: upstart, init

I know that Raring use upstart as init system. However I'm wondering if it's possible to switch to systemd, as we can do it on Debian. I've found this ppa: [systemd : Martin Pitt](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/systemd) But the `systemd` version proposed is old.

Has anyone installed `systemd` on raring? How?

Answer (score 2):

I don't provide packages for outdated releases, so you will have to upgrade to saucy first, but you can try installing systemd from my [ppa:ondrej/systemd](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/systemd).

Comment: Thanks. I've upgraded my OS to saucy since. Also, Ubuntu will switch for systemd : [Mark Shuttleworth &raquo; Blog Archive &raquo; Losing graciously](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316)!